# show images from database with id

Tags: php, sql, image, fetch

I have this code :

```
<?php
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("galeria",$link);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT lowsrc from gallery WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$x=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$image = $row['lowsrc'];
echo "<img src='".$image."' /><br />";

}
?>
```

and in the table I have this one :

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
echo '<td><img src="getImage.php?id=' . $row[0].'" width="300"  /></td>';
```

[image]

[image]

I cant figure out why this is not showing the images

Comment: Because you did not specify your image path.Specify  full path not only image name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify full path.
For e.g: `src="'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']/getImage.php?id=' . $row[0].'"`

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
echo '<td><img src="http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/getImage.php?id=' . $row[0].'" width="300"  /></td>';
```

Comment: give your full url please?

Comment: please give your image src

Comment: it will not worked as your base url not exist. what is your domain name?

Comment: I have edited code use it and give me your image src. @Natalino

Comment: with this question throw http://localhost/psi/getImage.php?id=9 The Image is shown

Comment: please accept the answer if my help and answer useful to you. :) @Natalino

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting HTML twice.

```
  $image = $row['lowsrc'];
  header('Content-type:image/png');
  readfile($image);
```

You'll notice that this will cause the URL `getimage.php?id=9` to behave like a PNG image and the read file command will dump the contents of the file.

If this doesn't work, download the image, open it with a text editor and check for PHP errors.

Comment: i think this dont work with me because I store the url of the img on the database   , yep not worked

Comment: Wait, what kind of content do you store in the database? Is it a URL? Do you have any samples?